# Android - Start App Upon Phone Call

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to develop an app that starts up when a user receives a phone call? I can't really go into details about the idea but was wondering if there was some call that would allow that to happen.

Comment: yes it is possible.. what you had tried or what you had search related to this...?? can you share with us.?

Comment: I haven't started anything yet. I was going to work on a little project after finals. Thank you all for pointing me in the right  direction!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Broadcast Receiver for thatlike this

```
public class PhoneStatReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{        
    private static final String TAG = "PhoneStatReceiver"; 
    private static boolean incomingFlag = false;
    private static String incoming_number = null;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)){                        
                    incomingFlag = false;
                    String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);        
                    Log.i(TAG, "call OUT:"+phoneNumber);                        

            }else{                        
                    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Service.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);                        
                    switch (tm.getCallState()) {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                            incomingFlag = true;//标识当前是来电
                            incoming_number = intent.getStringExtra("incoming_number");
                        Log.i(TAG, "RINGING :"+ incoming_number);
                            break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:                                
                            if(incomingFlag){
                                    Log.i(TAG, "incoming ACCEPT :"+ incoming_number);
                            }
                            break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:                                
                            if(incomingFlag){
                                    Log.i(TAG, "incoming IDLE");                                
                            }
                            break;
                    } 
            }

    }

}
```

Register this receiver in AndroidManifest like this

```
<receiver android:name=".filter.PhoneStatReceiver">  

            <intent-filter>

                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>           

                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />

            </intent-filter>

</receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes We can start an diffrent app when User receives a phone call.Example :- Truecaller,Mobile no. Tracker apps.
You can use Services for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        final Context cont = context;
        final Intent in = intent;

        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent i = new Intent(cont, MainActivity.class);
                        i.putExtras(in);
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                        cont.startActivity(i);
                    }
                }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

You must implement this handler with postDelayed so that your activity screen can be on top of native call screen. If you dont want this to happen then you must remove this handler.

Add these to your manifest--

```
<receiver
     android:name=".CallReceiver"
     android:enabled="true" >
     <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS" />
```

You have to use another extra_state for onreceiving call. This is for ringing state.